# How do we confirm SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement is success?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the following code to confirm the SQL result

```
int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
if (i > 0) {
    System.out.println("success");
} else {
    System.out.println("stuck somewhere");
}
```

JavaDoc says "executeUpdate returns"

> either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statementsor (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Now, we have done partitioning using TRIGGER and my INSERT query returns 0 for all Insert queries and records are inserted into appropriate partitions.

So, now I have to remove the check for success and rely on SQLEXCEPTION for errors.

Can I ignore the following check and trust the records are Inserted/Updated in DB.

```
if (i > 0) {
    System.out.println("success");
} else {
    System.out.println("stuck somewhere");
}
```

Comment: The exact behavior you see could even change if you were to change your underlying database.  So, I vote for the try-catch option to know if the DML were successful or not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Its Postgres. Just added the tag. Thanks

Comment: That sounds as if your are using and old Postgres version. With Postgres 11 and [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) this will work correctly. If you really need partitioning for performance reasons, you should upgrade to Postgres 11 anyway.